# PHP not getting $_POST inputs from form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working with PHP `mail()` and have a contact form which `posts` the input fields `submit`. **All** inputs on the html form have a `name` attr attached to them so PHP can retrieve their values.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" role="form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```

On `submit` the form is `posted` to `sendemail.php` to retrieve the input values and send the email:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'keilcarpenter01@gmail.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

As you can see I am attempting to retrieve the forms values by:

```
$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));
```

Which is referencing the correct names attributed to the name of each form input

But its not getting the actual values so when i get an email all the body of the message contains is:

```
Name:
Email:
Subject:
Message:
```

And not the actual contents of the feilds.

I have read that PHP does not parse POST when your enctype different from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` but I dont have any `enctype` attr on my `form`.

result of var_dump($_POST):

```
  array(0) {
}
```

I cant see where I have gone wrong

Comment: Don't suppress errors (**`@`**), fix your code and handle errors.

Comment: Plus, if you're using related JS here, show it.

Comment: Hi Fred, that is also what I was asking, but haven't get no answer untill now.

Comment: hey sorry, not using js just php mail()

Comment: nothing wrong with your code, besides the missing (*what I said up there*) subject name attribute. can't help anymore than I already have.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me what this is doing in your php file?

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );
```

Are you submitting the form trough an ajax call.

Is also important to note as @Darren say, remove those '@' from your code, you don't need it. This will suppress errors in the function if any!

Maybe you can try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault;

            var form = $('form#main-contact-form');

            var formAction = form.attr('action');

            $.ajax({
                url: formAction,
                data : form.serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                type : 'POST',
            })
            .done(function(data) {
               //here is your returned array
               if(data.type == 'success'){
                   alert(data.message)
               }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })


    })
})
```

Comment: no ajax here, just an array containing test for email being sent. echoed in json format if it is

Comment: You can echo reults in a PHP, nothing wrong with it, but you can not get it in this way if you don't use an ajax call to get your response back, so I am wondering why you do this in this way.

Comment: thats just the way iv always dont it. I will get var_dump list see what it comes up with

Comment: I have updated my answer so have a look at it. Note that your submit button has now an 'ID' and the 'header' is been commented.

Comment: Any Time, if you need more help with this just let me know. By the way, I suppose you know that you need to put the javascript inside a <script> tag at the end of your page and have jquery referenced. And learning this approach will make your life easy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the raw format like this.

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

And then access like this

```
$email = $post->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out it, it turns out that the class `.contact-form` eas already tied to a `js` function which used ajax to pass data to the php script. At the time it wasnt catching any data from the form hence why `$_POST` was recieving no value.

I fixed the error by passing the form values:

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function (evt) {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post('sendemail.php',{ name: $('input[name=name]').val() email: $('input[name=email]').val() message: $('input[name=message]').val() }, function(data) {;
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Are there any related JS functions? Seems like a problem related to a library or script thats handling the form instead of the standard POST.